# How can I print from within the Code app?

Tags: code

I cannot seem to find a button or selection in the Code application to print an open document.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm,`Ctrl P` doesn't work either... Amazingly enough, it seems, the printing functionality hasn't been implemented into Code. Well, if you need this feature, you can suggest to implement it via the dedicated [elementary/code](https://github.com/elementary/code/issues) github page.